# Can you use Third Person Mode without losing the Crosshair?

Tags: portal-2

I am wondering if anyone knows how to turn on the third person mode without losing the crosshair? Is there any way of doing it? Without a crosshair it's unplayable, as far as i am concerned.

Comment: Internet says: "Draw a dot with a temporary marker" :/

Comment: Yeah,  I know, unfortunately thats not an option running an VR-Headset :P Wouldnt do it anyways, even with my normal monitor :D

Comment: Using a VR headset and using third person is like buying a car and walking.

Comment: It's like buying a gaming pc and only browsing facebook

Comment: Dont you use your car just for show-off? :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have version 13.0 or higher you should go to options and have a three notch bar for different views. View one is first person. Views two and three are third person. If you go to view two, another option is to turn on crosshairs. You can only turn on crosshairs while in first person.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sorry, I can't follow you, can you make some screenshots? And are you saying, it is not possible to turn it on for third person view?